# How to protect disabled or readonly input in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a view continent an input that I want it to be disabled or readonly so I want users can't be change his value, but when I do right click inspect and I removed word 'readonly' or 'disabled' the input be activated and I can change his value and when I click with submit button the new value has saved, I blocked to find a solution of this problem.

Employe Model :

```
namespace Project1.Entities
{
    public class Employe : EntityBase
    {        
        public string? Name { get; set; }
       
    }
}
```

EntityBase contient tow property with the default value

```
namespace Project1.Entities
{
    public class EntityBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
         
        public string FirstUserInsertedData { get; set; } = "TestDefaultValue";

        public DateTime FirstDateInserted { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;        

    }
}
```

Edit View

```
@model Project1.Entities.Employe

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Employe</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstUserInsertedData" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstUserInsertedData" readonly class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstUserInsertedData" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstDateInserted" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstDateInserted" readonly class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstDateInserted" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

EmployesController :

```
#nullable disable
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Project1.Entities;
using Web.DBContext;

namespace Project1.Controllers
{
    public class EmployesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public EmployesController(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Employes
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Employes.ToListAsync());
        }       

        // GET: Employes/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var emp = new Employe(); // => just to set the default value of 'FirstUserInsertedData' and 'FirstDateInserted'
            return View(emp);
        }

        // POST: Employes/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name,Id,FirstUserInsertedData,FirstDateInserted")] Employe employe)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(employe);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(employe);
        }

        // GET: Employes/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var employe = await _context.Employes.FindAsync(id);
            if (employe == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(employe);
        }

        // POST: Employes/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Name,Id,FirstUserInsertedData,FirstDateInserted")] Employe employe)
        {
            if (id != employe.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(employe);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!EmployeExists(employe.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(employe);
        }


        // GET: Employes/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var employe = await _context.Employes
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (employe == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(employe);
        }


        // GET: Employes/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var employe = await _context.Employes
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (employe == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(employe);
        }

        // POST: Employes/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var employe = await _context.Employes.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Employes.Remove(employe);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool EmployeExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Employes.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

When you see this list of employe whe have First user 'Admin' and First Date Is 2022-02-02
[Picture of List of Employes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5nob.png)

Edit View before inspict :

[Picture1 of Edit View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qNPZ.png)

Edit View After inspict and remove readonly key word :

[Picture2 of Edit View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agtor.png)

[Picture of List of Employes after Edit and inspict input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lEpz.png)

and when i remove the property from Edit action in Employescontroller ([Bind("Name,Id")])
his saved data with changing user name 'Admin' with the default value => 'TestDefaultValue'

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Name,Id")] Employe employe)
        {
            if (id != employe.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(employe);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!EmployeExists(employe.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(employe);
        }
```

[After Edit and Saved Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv3wH.png)

**I know it's a trivial problem but I'm new to asp.net core and I need help**

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I assume this is on the web? There are many ways to do this, input validation must not only be in the UI but also on the controller. So you shouldnt include the property change in your controller code.

Comment: yes i removed the property from Bind exists in the Edit method from the controller but he saved with the default value, he declare in classe public string? FirstUser { get; set; } = "Admin";

Comment: youssef please include your controller code in the question

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I renewed my question

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is Create a ViewModel;

```
public class EmployeeViewModel {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string FirstUserInsertedData { get; set; }
   public DateTime FirstDateInserted { get; set; }
}
```

Then use that in your Edit action. Since the view model isn't attached to the actual entity, we need to find that record in the database then update the properties you want.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Name,Id,FirstUserInsertedData,FirstDateInserted")] EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel)
{
   if (id != employeeViewModel.Id)
   {
      return NotFound();
   }

   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      try
      {
         // find the actual employee record
         var employe = _context.Employe.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.Id == id);

         if(employe != null)
         {
            // update the properties you want
            // the other properties will remain unmodified
            employe.Name = employeeViewModel.Name;
         }

         _context.Update(employe);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
      }
      catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
      {
         if (!EmployeExists(employe.Id))
         {
            return NotFound();
         }
         else
         {
            throw;
         }
      }
      return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
   }
   return View(employe);
}
```

Comment: Think you very match to traying to help my. i find the solution juste to add this ligne in the same controller to be like that 

var emp = this._context.Employes.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id==id);
                    emp.Name = employe.Name;

                    _context.Update(emp);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();